# Como definir chaves e valores 'default' para array passado como parâmetro em PHP?

Tags: php, php-7, array-associativo

Fiz uma função que recebe diversos argumentos, e decidi passá-los por um `array` para ser executada. Ex:

```
public function funcTeste(array $dados){
    return \count($dados);
}
```

Mas esse array deve possuir um número padrão de chaves (como se eu dissesse `$dados = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`, ou algo do tipo).

Mais do que isso, se esse array possuir parâmetros não passados (como se o usuário passar como parâmetro `['key1' => 'cavalo', 'key2' => 'avestruz']`) há uma forma de, na função, preencher esse valor com um `default`?

Estou usando PHP `7.1.23`

Comment: Se precisa que seja um valor definido e com valores padrões, por que utilizou o *array* e não definiu os argumentos separadamente?

Comment: achei que ficaria mais fácil de passar os parâmetros, principalmente em funções com `n` parâmetros requeridos, onde, se trocar a ordem de dois deles, quebra o cálculo inteiro

Comment: não sei ao certo se existe o que procuro, mas, se existir, vai ser uma mão na roda

Comment: Terá que fazer as condições dentro da função para garantir o que precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_fill_key()` para gerar um array com todas as chaves obrigatorias e apenas um valor para todas. Ao final chame `array_merge()` que vai mesclar o array padrão e o passado pelo usuário sendo que o array mais a direita (último) vai sobrescrever os valores com chaves iguais.

```
$padrao =  array_fill_keys(['k1', 'k2', 'k3'], 'valor padrão');
$arr = ['k1' => 'v1', 'k3' => 'v3'];

$novo = array_merge($padrao, $arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [k1] => v1
    [k2] => valor padrão
    [k3] => v3
)
```

Comment: Funcionou, combinei o `array_merge` com um array que criei agora no construtor para definir os diversos valores diferentes para o `array`.